# Why animating the element width causes other elements in the same row to jerk a little?

Tags: css, transition

I have a row of elements and a CSS hover animation that causes the hovered element to expand twice the original width. It works fine if hovering between two adjecant elements, hovewer if you move the mouse quickly over a multiple elements at once, elements further down the row is jerking for a few pixels forwards and backwards for whatever reason.

Example in this Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p8z7c0jy/2/

1. Try to quickly move the mouse between the any two adjecant elements (e.g.
   between red and orange) - everything works fine. One of these two
   becomes larger, other becomes smaller as it should, and other elements remain the same
   size.
2. Now try to quickly move the mouse over a distance two elements (e.g. red to yellow) - you will notice that purple and blue element size changes slightly, while they shouldn't - they seem to jerk a bit, which looks ugly and irratating.

At first I thought that maybe a CSS easing is causing this problem (different elements animating between "wide" and "narrow" states at different speeds), but this is happening even with linear animation easing (shown in the aformentioned Fiddle).

Can someone please explain why is that happening and **how to prevent further elements jerking during animation**?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.child:hover {
  flex: 2;
}

.red {background: red;}
.orange {background: orange;}
.yellow background: yellow;}
.purple {background: purple;}
.blue {background: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child red">
    Element 1
  </div>
    <div class="child orange">
    Element 2
  </div>
    <div class="child yellow">
    Element 3
  </div>
    <div class="child purple">
    Element 4
  </div>
    <div class="child blue">
    Element 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For questions like this, it’s important to mention what browser (and its version) and on which operating system you are using.

On macOS Safari 14.0.2 your example runs without any "jerking" but rather smooth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a smooth transition that doesn't trigger instantly on hover(which causes "jerking"), you should add a delay to the transition, so moving between elements doesn't cause an undesired effect.

**See:** [transition-delay property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay)

If you want a more aesthetically pleasing transition beyond that, I suggest using [cubic-bezier.](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67)